# From R to Scala. How can I read a CSV in Scala, save it to a res slot and then combined those res slots into a sample csv?

Tags: r, scala, csv

I want to create a random sample from a large dataset. Had a 6gb Kaggle dataset

The way I'd iteratively doe this in R is the following:

```
ctr <- read.csv("train.csv", nrow = 1000000) # importing by parts
ctr_sample <- sample(nrow(ctr), nrow(ctr)*0.1) 
ctr_1 <- ctr[ctr_sample,] # creating 10% sample
nrow(ctr_1)
rm(ctr)

ctr2 <-  read.csv("train.csv", header = TRUE,nrow = 1000000, skip = 1000000, 
col.names = c("id","click", "hour","C1", "banner_pos", "site_id"  , "site_domain", 
"site_category", "app_id" , "app_domain" ,"app_category", "device_id", "device_ip",
"device_model","device_type","device_conn_type", "C14" , "C15", "C16", "C17", "C18", 
"C19", "C20" , "C21"))
ctr_sample <- sample(nrow(ctr2), nrow(ctr2)*0.1)
ctr_2 <- ctr2[ctr_sample,]
nrow(ctr_2)
rm(ctr2)

}
```

I continue this for ctr2, ctr3...all the way to ctr7 and then combine them  with rbind in R to ctr_set and export them to a sampling csv.

However in Scala I don't know how to read only 1,000 lines from a CSV and then skip the next 1000 lines, take a 0.1 sample, store it into a res0,1,2 then combine those res's by rows and export that entire sample as a PDF

Anyone good in both languages? I am a student and can use a tutor

Comment: As for the first part, Source.fromFile("myfile.csv").getLines().take(1000) or .drop(1000) allows you to read 1000 lines or skip 1000.

Comment: If you used Spark, it has ways of taking samples (see`sample` here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD). Not sure if you need a specific way of sampling, though

Answer (score 1):

To perform **rbind** in Spark, you can use **RDD.union** function as follows:

```
val ctr_1 = sc.textFile("ctr_1")
val ctr_2 = sc.textFile("ctr_2")
val combine = ctr_1.union(ctr_2)
```